# how to assign %%? to variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

```
FOR %%? IN (file_to_be_queried) DO (
    ECHO File Name Only       : %%~n?
    ECHO File Extension       : %%~x?
    ECHO Name in 8.3 notation : %%~sn?
    ECHO File Attributes      : %%~a?
    ECHO Located on Drive     : %%~d?
    ECHO File Size            : %%~z?
    ECHO Last-Modified Date   : %%~t?
    ECHO Parent Folder        : %%~dp?
    ECHO Fully Qualified Path : %%~f?
    ECHO FQP in 8.3 notation  : %%~sf?
    ECHO Location in the PATH : %%~dp$PATH:?
)
```

I saw this at http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_fileproperties.php.

But when I try to apply it,
In the loop and i using "set"

SET datetime_t = %%~t?

Echo datetime_t %datetime_t% > result.txt

inside the file only shown

```
datetime_t
datetime_t
datetime_t
datetime_t
```

what happen to this variable?is it empty?

Comment: yes - %%-Variables are only valid in the current block between `(` and `)` and not existent outside of this block.

Comment: Don't use a wildcard in a for loop variable.  It is poor practice for people trying to learn by reading your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Rem Above is required for this to work

FOR %%? IN (file_to_be_queried) DO (
ECHO File Name Only       : %%~n?
ECHO File Extension       : %%~x?
ECHO Name in 8.3 notation : %%~sn?
ECHO File Attributes      : %%~a?
ECHO Located on Drive     : %%~d?
ECHO File Size            : %%~z?
ECHO Last-Modified Date   : %%~t?
ECHO Parent Folder        : %%~dp?
ECHO Fully Qualified Path : %%~f?
ECHO FQP in 8.3 notation  : %%~sf?
ECHO Location in the PATH : %%~dp$PATH:?

SET datetime_t=%%~t?
Echo datetime_t !datetime_t! > result.txt
Rem Notice use of "!"
)
```

And that should work fine.

Mona

Comment: Hi, I wish to ask that, in a for loop, I saw some coding with %%?,%%#.Is it same meaning as a temporary variable like %%a, %%b that used in a for loop? or it bringing out the special meaning with the use of ? and #. I don't how to identify this problem as google are not accepting special character.

Comment: @user2940018 The use of `?` or '#' is just to show that you can substitute with any letter you want. It can be used for some other purposes, but you don't need to worry about that.